# how to call angular js factory class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to call scrolltop function after the form save. I write factory class for access everywhere in my application. but factory calling is not working.

this is my factory class

```
    .factory('scrollTop', function () {
    return {
        start: function () {
            $window.scrollTo(0, angular.element(document.getelementsbyclassname('validation-position')).offsetTop);  
        },

    };
})
```

i called this function in side the save function.

```
     $scope.saveUpdateUserDetails = function (id) {
        if (id == undefined) {
            $scope.saveUser();
            $scope.scrollTop.start();
        } else {

            $scope.updateUser(id);
            $scope.scrollTop.start();
        }
    };
```

but error said " Cannot read property 'start' of undefined". How i call my factory function inside the save function.

Comment: have you added this factory as a dependency to the component ?

Comment: Yes i added it correctly

Answer (score 0):

**you must inject your factory or service in your controller definition** like this sample of code

```
app.controller('MyController',['$scope','scrollTop',function($scope, scrollTop){
$scope.saveUpdateUserDetails = function (id) {
        if (id == undefined) {
            $scope.saveUser();
            scrollTop.start();
        } else {

            $scope.updateUser(id);
            scrollTop.start();
        }
    };
}]);
```